# How to able CI to continue working after it finishes e2e test

Tags: jenkins, protractor, angular-cli, jenkins-pipeline

I have this test running on CI but after it finishes it stall the whole process. How can I able to stop or allow to process to continue with `Deploy`?

```
[1]   Audit Log Viewer - Grid
[1]     ✓ should not show extra columns when moving from "asset/alert/cases" to other application
[1] 
[1] Executed 1 of 20 specs INCOMPLETE (19 SKIPPED) in 20 secs.
[1] [12:14:11] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[1] [12:14:11] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
[1] ng e2e -s false -pc proxy.conf.json exited with code 0
```

**Stack:**

```
 1. Angular 5.x
 2. Typescript
 3. Angular-Cli
```

Comment: Can you please add some more information? For example, how are you trying to run the test, the bash script you're using on Jenkins.

Comment: @Ibrahim I've solved the issue by separating the npm run "" had been using concurrently and this is what halted my process.

Comment: Please provide an answer and mark this as solved.

Comment: @Michael agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I was using `concurrently /dist/app.js && npm run e2e`

I separated the calls and killing the /dist/app.js process after the tests are finished running.

That way it allows me to invoke `npm run e2e` without stalling the process.